# Большой POST запрос

Tags: php, javascript

Бьюсь второй день над следующей задачей:
есть база данных адресов типа "область", "город", "улица", "дом" и т.д.
необходимо сделать механизм добавления комментариев, к которым будет привязан список адресов, причём к комментарию может быть привязан любой уровень, например:

1. "не назначать подключение в субботу", связанный с адресом
   "московская область, г.Королёв"
2. "не назначать на воскресенье", связанный с адресами
   "московская область, г.Королёв, пр. Космонавтов д5"
   "московская область, г.Королёв, пр. Космонавтов д6"
   "московская область, г.Королёв, пр. Космонавтов д7"
   "московская область, г.Королёв, пр. Космонавтов д8"

Соответственно, при передачи комментария с кучей привязанных адресов я имею огромный `$_POST`, который просто рубится. 
Пробовал протащить через `$_COOKIE` — результат тот же. 
Рассматриваю в качестве варианта разделение запросов на куски — по одному на адрес и передача таковых аяксом... 
Единственной ли это вариант или можно сделать более красиво?

UP: извиняюсь, ввёл в заблуждение, апач выдаёт ошибку 414, не заметил сразу её в логах в конце запроса.

**post_max_size**   64M
**upload_max_filesize**  32M 
 **memory_limit** 128M... 
причём размер пришедших данных постоянно разный! Что за бред такой? Может, дело в Phalcon`е, который установлен?

Comment: Насколько огромный? Размеры. Можно попробовать оптимизировать, заменяя, где это возможно, список диапазоном, но это лечение симптомов. Рубится - это превышает максимальный размер запроса? Тогда его можно увеличить.

Comment: Может, стоит разобраться, почему "огромный $_POST" у Вас "рубится"? И соответственно перенастроить сервер, чтобы не рубился.

Comment: В зависимости от ситуации. Я думаю, что для реальной работы необходимо предусмотреть ~16К символов.

Comment: Yaant, крутил конфиги PHP, такие директивы как post_max_size,
upload_max_filesize, max_input_vars - эффекта нет. Если рубит браузер - разбираться не буду, ибо это есть решение для конкретной машины и этим путём идти нельзя.

Comment: @Afftobus, посмотри еще конфиги веб-сервера (nginx, apache или другой).

Comment: Даниель, для моего апача на форумах рекомендуют прописать в .htaccess прописывать LimitRequestBody. Этот путь уже тоже прошел...

Comment: @Afftobus Да нет, это у Вас чисто серверная проблема. Для браузеров лимит POST запроса — порядка 2 Гб (а то и больше, может зависеть от браузера). Иначе как бы в них работала загрузка файлов на любые сайты?

Comment: А что значит "рубится" ? запрос не появляется в логах на  сервере вообще. появляется, но в логах ошибок что то пишется, что конкретно пишется. что возвращается в браузер клиенту при этом. Может вы пытаетесь это все целиком в БД записать и т.к. БД и запросы не оптимизированы то просто слетаете по времени выполнения

Comment: @Afftobus, ну, мне пока не хватает данных. Код ошибки? Что было выяснено дебагом? Распространенная конфигурация апача - проксирвоание через энжинкс, если в данном случае это так, то его конфиги так же нужно рассмотреть, т.к. он первый в очереди. В общем больше информации было бы хорошо увидеть. Может вся эта радост ьпишется в базу и та не справляется, а может просто таймаут истекает. Всякое может быть.

Comment: Основную массу информации я передаю в виде json текста. В логах ошибки не вижу. Когда на принимающей странице вывожу print_r($_POST), то вижу пару переменных в нормальном виде, потом обрубленный текст json данных, причем обрубленный на середине Unicode символа. Последующие переменные отсутствуют вообще... Нджинкса нет, чистый апач.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается через `php.ini` свойства:

`post_max_size` - Общий размер `POST` запроса по умолчанию 8Мб

`upload_max_filesize` - размер файла который можно загрузить на сервер через `POST`.

Очень важно что бы значения были:

`memory_limit > post_max_size > upload_max_filesize`

Так же, не збываем, что бы скрипту хватило времени "пережевать" данные `max_execution_time`

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

**UPD**

1) Если верить этим двум ссылкам то похоже данные приходят через GET. Попробуйте посмотреть в apache access.log URL запросов.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/apache.html

2) Можете попробовать получить тело запроса напрямую через:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
parse_str($data, $result)

var_dump($result);
```

и посмотреть всё ли пришло.

3) Ну и apache тоже умеет "обрезать" POST запросы посмотрите:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Answer (score 0):

У меня было подобная проблема но в другой задаче. Нужно было синхронизировать таблицы базы данных. В конечно счёте сделали так. Массив с данными делили на куски и отправляли в цикле . Вот пример кода.

```
$recordChunks = array_chunk($rd[0]['RECORDS'], 7000); 
            foreach ($recordChunks as $chunk) {
                $rd[0]['RECORDS'] = $chunk;
                $request = array(
                    'TOKEN' => $this->getContainer()->getParameter('cdb_token'),
                    'DATA' => json_encode(array(
                        "DB_VERSION" => $dbVersion,
                        "DATA" => $rd,
                    )),
                );
                $size += strlen($request['DATA']);
                //отправка данных на ЦБД
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getContainer()->getParameter('https_cdb_from'));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/адрес.pem');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

                // получить json ответ
                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                $data = json_decode($response);
                if (($data->STATUS != 1) || (is_null($data))) {
                    var_dump($table, count($chunk),$rd);
                    $this->em->getFilters()->enable('softdeleteable');
                    throw new \Exception('Ошибка на ЦБД');
                }
                unset($request);
            }
            unset($rd);
```

Comment: не смогу воспользоваться данным методом, т.к. JSON строку формирую JavaScript`ом, соответственно, чтобы его обработать PHP, мне его надо просунуть в другую страницу, а проблема именно в просовывании.